# generate <optGroupTag> from a json

Tags: jquery

i have a josn data like this

`{ name: [ 'a', 'b' ],
  property: [ 'art', 'test' ] }`

From this how can i create an `<optgroupTag>`
with `lables`  `name ,property`
name `values` `a,b,c`
property values `art,test`

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="name">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="property">
    <option value="art">art</option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: i dont know how to perfrom this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Basically You have to iterate you JSON

```
var data = {
    name: ['a', 'b'],
    property: ['art', 'test']
};
var html = '';
for (var item in data) {
    html += '<optgroup label="' + item + '">';
    $.each(data[item], function (innerItem, index) {
        html += '<option value="' + innerItem+ '">' + innerItem+ '</option>';
    })
    html += '</optgroup>'
}
$('select').html(html);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tCf47/1/)

```
var data = {
    name: ['a', 'b'],
    property: ['art', 'test']
};
var html = '';
for (var item in data) {
    html += '<optgroup label="' + item + '">';
    $.each(data[item], function (index, value) {
        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
    })
    html += '</optgroup>'
}
$('select').html(html);
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/tCf47/2/)

Comment: how can get values as art', 'test' etc